# Migrating from SOAP to REST (Java)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, restful-architecture

When migrating from SOAP based webservices to RESTful, how complicated is the task? I have worked on them individually, but never on any migration. Can any one tell me the points that need to be taken into consideration when doing this? Not sure if its an appropriate question. More like a discussion thing.

Answer (score 2):

The general approach on any situation like that can be to have a middle adapter/layer work between your existing system and newly developed system.

Converting an existing SOAP web service into RESTful web service can be tedious depending upon the complexity of existing system. Rather we can take alternative approach where an REST Adapter can be written that acts as a mediator between existing SOAP system and freshly developed REST web service.

This way can be done with minimum efforts and delivery can be fast. But again it depends on what is the system all about, how complex is current SOAP web service.

So with this approach end client will generate a REST request that will be landed on REST adapter and from Adapter to existing SOAP web service, takes back the response from your SOAP web service converts it back ready for REST client response. Intermediate JSON to XML and XML to JSON conversions can be easily handled.

This approach can be better as if required adapter can be turned off. This